# Sum the same cell in a range of sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B6),"",SUM(Sheet1:Sheet10!O6)+Sheet11!P6+Sheet12!T6)
```

I would like to use this spreadsheet in Google Sheets so I can get it on other devices and collaborate, etc.

When I imported the Excel sheet to a Google Sheet it changed the formula to:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B6),"",SUM(Sheet1!O6)+Sheet11!P6+Sheet12!T6)
```

It removed the range of referenced sheets in the first set of brackets after the `SUM`.  Does anyone know if Google Sheets can do this?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is you have to do `Sheet1!O6+Sheet2!O6+Sheet3!O6....`

Comment: Why not keep using Excel? It's available for all kinds of devices and online, too.